# asp.net listview : hide a div inside itemtemplate for every 3'rd item

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, listview

There are 3 x "lbl" for each row (width specified), and i'm appending a "spc" to make some room between each of the "lbl". Thing is... for every 3'rd item rendered out in the listview, i need to remove/hide the "spc" div.

I've googled and found some examples on how to do this, but none of them are sufficent in my scenario..

Anyone know how i can handle this ?

**CODE :**

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvLabels" ItemType="ServiceLayer.Models.AnsattOrderSummary">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="lbl">
                <span class="lbl-inner">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <span>
                            <%# Item.OrderedBy %> ( <%# Item.AnsattNr %> )
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="spc">&nbsp;</div>  This must be hidden for every 3'rd item.
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Please test this: `div.spc:nth-of-type(3n){display:none;`

Comment: @FarzinKanzi : YOU ... are awsome ! :) Please post this as the correct answer.. Best and easiest solution ever!.

Comment: You welcome my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove 3rd `divs.spc` you can do this:

```
div.spc:nth-of-type(3n){
  display:none;
}
```